# Scsm Web Part authentication failed

Tags: c#, sharepoint, download

Hello i am writting a web part for sharepoint 2010 in which i download attachments from specific incidents in scsm. My Problem is that when I debug it on the server everything works fine but if I try to download anything on a client i get the following error:

```
[FaultException: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.]
   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ThrowIfNegotiationFault(Message message, EndpointAddress target) +15492698
   System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.ThrowIfFault(Message message, EndpointAddress target) +18
   System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState) +169

[SecurityNegotiationException: The caller was not authenticated by the service.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +10266458
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +539
   Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common.Internal.IDispatcherService.Connect(SdkClientConnectionOptions connectionOptions) +0
   Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common.Internal.SdkDataLayerProxyCore.ConnectInternal(EnterpriseManagementConnectionSettings connectionSettings) +269
   Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common.Internal.SdkDataLayerProxyCore.Initialize(EnterpriseManagementConnectionSettings connectionSettings, SdkChannelObject`1 channelObjectDispatcherService) +294
   Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common.Internal.SdkDataLayerProxyCore.CreateEndpoint(EnterpriseManagementConnectionSettings connectionSettings, SdkChannelObject`1 channelObjectDispatcherService) +1205

[UnauthorizedAccessEnterpriseManagementException: The user does not have sufficient permission to perform the operation.]
   Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common.Internal.ExceptionHandlers.HandleChannelExceptions(Exception ex) +2026
   Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common.Internal.SdkDataLayerProxyCore.CreateEndpoint(EnterpriseManagementConnectionSettings connectionSettings, SdkChannelObject`1 channelObjectDispatcherService) +905
   Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common.Internal.SdkDataLayerProxyCore.ConstructEnterpriseManagementGroupInternal(EnterpriseManagementConnectionSettings connectionSettings, ClientDataAccessCore clientCallback) +199
   Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common.Internal.SdkDataLayerProxyCore.RetrieveEnterpriseManagementGroupInternal(EnterpriseManagementConnectionSettings connectionSettings, ClientDataAccessCore callbackDispatcherService) +482
   Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common.Internal.SdkDataLayerProxyCore.Connect(EnterpriseManagementConnectionSettings connectionSettings, ClientDataAccessCore callbackDispatcherService) +295
   Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.EnterpriseManagementGroup.InternalInitialize(EnterpriseManagementConnectionSettings connectionSettings, EnterpriseManagementGroupInternal internalsProxy) +78
   downloadAttachmentWP.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl.listFilesBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +2583
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

What can be the cause of this error?